# SQL Server query with batch script

Tags: sql-server-2005, batch-file

I need to exec this sql query on my Windows SQL Server 2005, can i do this with a batch script?

The sql query

```
UPDATE VI_CURR_INFO SET 
    ends_days = '2005', 
    check_code = '1', 
    memb_name = '123132', 
    memb_guid = '1', 
    sno__numb = '1', 
    Bill_Section = '6', 
    Bill_Value = '3', 
    Bill_Hour = '6', 
    Surplus_Point = '6', 
    Increase_Days = '0'
```

The database name is "test1". 
How to perform a batch script to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a script file that looks like this:

```
use test1
go

UPDATE VI_CURR_INFO
SET ends_days = '2005', 
    check_code = '1', 
    memb_name = '123132', 
    memb_guid = '1', 
    sno__numb = '1', 
    Bill_Section = '6', 
    Bill_Value = '3', 
    Bill_Hour = '6', 
    Surplus_Point = '6', 
    Increase_Days = '0'
```

Save this as a script file (`Script1.sql` for example).  And then use SQLCMD to run the script against an instance:

```
sqlcmd -S YourServerName[\YourInstanceName] -i C:\YourScriptFileDir\Script1.sql
```